# Is there a way to customize the name given to EC2 instances created by Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

By default it seems that Elastic Beanstalk (EB) will name any EC2 instances it creates by the name of your EB environment. I've set up auto-scaling and am hoping to provide a custom name for instances created by the auto-scaling without having to make the changes manually. Is there a way to achieve this?